# Linear algebra perpendicular vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do I know the vectors that are perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,2,3)$ lie on a line?, thanks beforehand, I'll appreciate any help here.

Comment: It's the intersection of two (non-parallel) planes in $3$-space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because those two vectors span a plane, and the orthogonal complement to this plane only has one more dimension to live in.

You know it's at least one dimensional because the cross product of the two vectors lies in it, and it can't be any more than that since your space is only three dimensional.

Comment: thanks, how could I get that span, I don't know, maybe using dot product, linear combinations?, I'm actually stuck on it

Comment: @ChristianAndrews the span is, by definition, the set of linear combinations.

Comment: thanks so much, now I get it, sorry I can't vote up I'm so noob yet

Comment: @ChristianAndrews You can up vote if you register. And you can accept answers even without being registered. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).